# ASP.net Session Destroy if he closes the browser

Tags: asp.net

I have an website. When the user is logged the session details will loaded.
When the user logged out the session details will abandoned. (Log out by clicking the logout menu)
when the user simply closes the browser then how to destroy the session.

In the next time its get logging with the same session data. I need to avoid this.

Comment: This question lacks clarity, on the surface of it, it appears you are asking how to log out when someone simply closes the browser window, where as it seems you are asking how to remove session data when they log out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of your handling of the logout, call Session.Clear() to clear the key/value pairs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Page.Unload() isn't called when the user leaves the site, it's called when the engine is finished rendering it, right before HTML is sent to the browser. There is no access to the page through once that's happened.

I know in PHP you can use AJAX to call a PHP function with javascript. I don't know if this is possible with ASP.Net, or will work for sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting [post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2005/01/25/End-User-Sessions-When-the-Browser-Closes-With-Remote-Scripting.aspx) detailing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Page.OnUnload javascript event to make a request to a page that calls Session.Abandon(). This will cause the users session to be deleted whenever he leaves your site.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a persistent cookie to store the authentication ticket. Try setting the second parameter (createPersistentCookie) of the SetAuthCookie method to false, i.e. FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("myusername", false);

Answer (score 0):

```
try
    {
        Session["Admin"] = null;
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();                   
        Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Redirect("Dep_NewUserCreate.aspx");


    }
    catch(Exception ExLink)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Dep_NewUserCreate.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could configure your sessions to time out quicker.

In web.config:

```
< sessionState ... timeout="5" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have basically two options:

- Set time-out of your session cookies for 1 minute and send "keep-alive" AJAX request every 30 seconds.
- Don't use cookies, just pass session parameters in query.

Each solution will work on 99%, if you combine them, you should be pretty much set on 99.99% of cases. Depends how important this behavior is to you.