# How to destroy session in ASP.net when user navigates away from the page or exits the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have three session that I am setting navigating from my homepage to another page, like this:

```
Session["LocationText"] = locText;
Session["SpecialtyText"] = speText;
Session["GenderText"] = genText;

Response.Redirect("anotherpage.aspx", false);
```

Once I am in `anotherpage.aspx`, and either I navigate away from the page or close the browser, I would like to destroy those variable. The whole idea is, if I come back to `anotherpage.aspx` and it wasn't redirected from the page from a button click, it will not have any sessions.

I tried the following:

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session.Remove("LocationText");
    Session.Remove("SpecialtyText");
    Session.Remove("GenderText");
}
```

When I navigated away from the page and came back to it, it didn't destroy the variables. How can I achieve what I am looking to do?

**UPDATE**:

homepage:

```
Context.Items["LocationText"] = locText;
Context.Items["SpecialtyText"] = speText;
Context.Items["GenderText"] = genText;
```

anotherpage:

```
if (Context.Items["LocationText"] != null && Context.Items["SpecialtyText"] != null && Context.Items["GenderText"] != null) {
    slcLocation.SelectedValue = Context.Items["LocationText"].ToString();
    slcSpecialty.SelectedValue = Context.Items["SpecialtyText"].ToString();
    slcGender.SelectedValue = Context.Items["GenderText"].ToString();
    this.onBtnClick();
}
```

Comment: "The whole idea is, if I come back to anotherpage.aspx, it will not have any sessions."  Then why store them in session in the first place?

Comment: because anotherpage.aspx uses those session variable to do a search query.

Comment: Try using `Context` instead of `Session`.  That seems more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: would appear to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283591/asp-net-session-destroy-if-he-closes-the-browser

Comment: I am coming from PHP background, so please provide an example :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge just change `Session` to `Context.Items`.

Comment: In the homepage? and don't do anything in anotherpage.aspx... right?

Comment: You'll _retrieve_ the values from `Context.Items` in `anotherpage.aspx`.

Comment: I updated my question... Is that what you mean? Does my update look like what you referred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `Session.Abandon()` on your `Page_Unload` event. You can start a new session  again.

Comment: That was my original plan but it seems Context.Items() is better?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, glad that it helped. Then it's time to accept the answer :).

Comment: This will work whether user navigates away or closes the browser window?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, closing the browser window will anyway remove sesions and yes it will work when someone navigates away. Also, you can as well use `session.clear()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and comment, it sounds like `Context` may be more appropriate than `Session`.  Variables in `Context` only live for the life of the current request.

Comment: I tried to replace Session with Context.Items but it did not work. :/